# Django&Javascript: add entry to ManyToManyField from template

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am a beginner of django, and I am now facing this problem of how to add entry into a ManyToManyField.
Here is my code in models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
# This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
user = models.OneToOneField(User)

# The additional attributes we wish to include for a user.
website = models.URLField(blank=True)
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

# Tree field is used to store user's favourite trees
tree = models.ManyToManyField(Tree, blank=True)


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

What I want to do is have a button in my template(e.g. tree.html), and if I click this button, the entry will be added into ManyToManyField in user profile's tree field.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried this ? `userprofle.tree.add(tree)`

Comment: Authenticated user clicks button and entry is added to her / his profile. Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^like_tree/(\d+)/$', views.like_tree, name='like_tree'),
    ...
]
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
@login_required
def like_tree(request, tree_id):
    tree = get_object_or_404(Tree, pk=tree_id)
    request.user.userprofile.tree.add(tree)
    return redirect(<specify redirect url here>)
```

template (change `'like_tree'` to actual URL name, e.g. `'myapp:like_tree'`)

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'like_tree' tree.id %}">
    <button type="submit">Like</button>
</form>
```

There are many options to render template, actually. [This also may be usefull (about Ajax and CSRF)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax).